# php code inside html not getting parsed

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a simple html form with multiple choice questions...the questions and their options are loading from mysql. to ensure that only one option gets selected for each question I set the name attribute for each radiobutton as options+the question no like options1,options2.... However the php code is not being parsed by any browser. I've been stuck on this for ages. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
<title>counter</title>
<script src="script1.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div class="none" id="start"><h1>Start the timer</h1></div>
<h1><label id="time">00</label></h1>
<?php 
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser= "root";
$dbpass= "testrun";
$dbname= "test";
$connect= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
die("Database connection failed:"); 
}
?>
<?php
$quest_no=1;
$query= "select * from question";
$result= mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if(!$result){
die("failed");
}
else{
echo '<form>';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$btngrp = "options".$quest_no ;
echo $btngrp;
echo '<div class="quests">'.$quest_no.$row["quest"].'</br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option1" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option1"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option2" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option2"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option3" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option3"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option4" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option4"].'</div></br>';
$quest_no++;
}

echo '</form>';
}
?>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($result);
 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The response content is null or the browser doesn't show anything?

Comment: rename the file from `name.html` to `name.php` perhaps?

Comment: it is a .php file @KIKOSoftware

Comment: the browser just shows the php code block.it doesn't get parsed.@MoshFeu

Comment: Is that true for all php files? In that case your webserver (are you using one?) does not support php. Also note that you cannot open php files directly in a browser. PHP should run on a webserver.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of wamp. The rest of the php in the code works fine. Its just this one in the html tag attribute that is not being parsed. @KIKOSoftware

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see it... sorry for first covering the basics:

```
echo '<div class="quests">'.$quest_no.$row["quest"].'</br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option1" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option1"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option2" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option2"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option3" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option3"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $btngrp; ?>" value="option4" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option4"].'</div></br>';
```

should be:

```
echo '<div class="quests">'.$quest_no.$row["quest"].'</br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$btngrp.'" value="option1" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option1"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$btngrp.'" value="option2" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option2"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$btngrp.'" value="option3" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option3"].'</div></br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="'$btngrp.'" value="option4" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option4"].'</div></br>';
```

Did that help?

Comment: Why isnt the php block working though...and I kinda dont understand this syntax.

Comment: The PHP block is part of a string, and you echo that string. Note the nesting of double quoted strings within a string made with single quotes.

Comment: why doesnt this work
`echo '<input type="radio" name="'<?php echo $btngrp; ?>'" value="option1" /><div class="opts">'.$row["option1"].'</div></br>';`
.using single quotes outside the php block

Comment: At the end of this point: `name="'`, you're parsing PHP and you've reached the end of a string. The PHP parser is expecting either a dot, to add something to the string, or a semi-colon, to end the echo. It cannot cope with `<` and will probably generate an error.